# How to refresh a div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to set up a refresh on div after an object array has received the necessary inputs and has been submitted for displaying. So far I've done this:

```
  var users = [
    {name: "John Smith", description: "Some chap", image: "None"},
    {name: "Elizabeth II", description: "A fancy lass", image: "None"}
  ];

  function arrayAdd() {
    var title_text = $("#title_text").val();
    var description_text = $("#description_text").val();
    var image_text = $("#image_text").val();

    users.push({name:title_text,description:description_text,image:image_text});
    console.log(users);

    for (var i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {
      $("#users").html(users[i]['name']);
    };
  }
```

But that only shows the last value added, can you please show me a way to mend this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is over-writing the entire HTML of the element on each iteration so only the last one is visible. Change this:

```
$("#users").html(users[i]['name']);
```

To:

```
$("#users").append(users[i]['name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, in the for loop you are using html, it replaces everything inside that element use .append() instead

```
$('#users').append(users[i]['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `html` to `append`. You're clearing the HTML on each iteration.

```
$("#users").empty();

for (var i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {
  $("#users").append(users[i]['name']);
};
```